# REST with nullable types?

Tags: c#, rest, soap, nullable

I've hit a brickwall. My REST implementation won't accept Nullable values.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Transactions?AccNo={AccNo}&CostCentreNo={CostCentreNo}&TransactionType={TransactionType}&Outstanding={Outstanding}&CheckStartDate={CheckStartDate}&CheckEndDate={CheckEndDate}")]
    List<Transactions> GetTransactions(Int32 AccNo, Int32 CostCentreNo, Int32 TransactionType, Boolean Outstanding, DateTime? CheckStartDate, DateTime? CheckEndDate);
```

Whereas my original SOAP implementation does. So is there a way around this? Or do I have to re-write my code?

I still don't quite get why a datetime must be nullable anyway to be set to null.

Comment: A zeroed-out DateTime still has an actual value, just like int, float, etc. This is the case with all value types, thus, Nullable's reason for existence.

Comment: A DateTime cannot be null because it is a struct, not a class. Structs behave a lot like value types.

Comment: Can you make `CheckStartDate` and `CheckEndDate` optional parameters (with `RouteParameter.Optional`) and then just optionally pass them in the query string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by QueryStringConverter. Nullable types is not.

You could wrap the parameters and pass it through POST as such;

```
[DataContract(Name = "Details", Namespace = "")]
public class Details
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 AccNo;
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 CostCentreNo;
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 TransactionType;
    [DataMember]
    public Boolean Outstanding;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? CheckStartDate;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? CheckEndDate;

    public Details()
    {}
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Transactions",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
List<Transactions> GetTransactions(Details details);
```

Opionally, you could pass the date as strings instead of DateTime, and then use DateTime.Parse() on the string on the receiving end.

Comment: So, I would be passing in a Json - list of parameters? Instead of individually. What are the cons to doing this? - Would you recommend it on all methods including those that dont use nullables?

Comment: Wrapping the parameters requires you to serialize the data before sending it to the service. As shown [here](http://blog.manglar.com/json-post-request/) while in your original solution you could specifiy parameters directly in the URL.

Comment: Which you would prefer using is dependant on what requirements you set to your service.
For example if you have clients using Linux connecting to the service, it would be simpler to have the parameters as strings directly in the URL rather than finding a way to serialize the object on a non-windows machine.

Comment: Ill investigate, and give it a try when I get chance. Cheers.

Comment: Oh, coming round to trying it, I realise you have created a custom class used for SOAP too. I would much prefer the parameters to be exposed in soap than a custom class that represents them.

Comment: As I mentioned at the bottom of my post, a solution could be to switch the Nullable DateTime objects to string objects instead, and pass the value "null" for null and .ToString() of the date otherwice.
Then on the receiving end you can create a Nullable DateTime object and set the object to null if the string equals "null". And if it's not "null", use DateTime.Parse("datestring") to parse the string back to a DateTime object.

Comment: that would work, in theory. but is open to all sorts of problems and confusion. If the string is incorrect formatted for example. And it broadcasts as wanting a string, not a datetime.