# C# - expose enumerated type over webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, enums

Ok, Im having major problems trying to expose this enumerated type over my webservice. It does not function in the same way as my custom classes, in terms of exposing them.

ServerSide:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public enum EventReportType {EventAutoContract, DailyAutoContract, EventFunctionSheet }
```

Clientside:

```
// For a custom class I would do:
ServerRef.MyClass maclass = new ServerRef.MyClass();
// but the following does not work.
ServerRef.EventReportType myenum = new ServerRef.EventReportType();
enum test = new ServerRef.EventReportType();
```

**I dont think its even in the WSDL, so how do I get it to expose properly?
And how would I consume and use it?**

Please look at my other question too for a bounty : [REST with nullable types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646027/rest-with-nullable-types)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the type is an `enum`, you don't create instances of it, you access static representations of values.

For instance,

```
var value = EventReportType.EventAutoContract;
```

But in general, you won't assign the value to a variable unless you need to, you would just use it explicitly; so, say calling a service method which accepts an enum value from this type:

```
myServiceCall(EventReportType.EventAutoContract);
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly spell out the `DataContractAttribute` either, this can be shorthanded to `DataContract`, also, you probably require each `enum` member to be augmented with the `EnumMember` attribute, too. So...

```
[DataContract]
public enum EventReportType 
{
    [EnumMember]
    EventAutoContract, 
    [EnumMember]
    DailyAutoContract, 
    [EnumMember]
    EventFunctionSheet 
}
```

You can find a reference for using enumeration types in data contracts [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx). Ultimately, if your `enum` is properly defined and used somewhere in the service which is exposed to the client side, then the `enum` will be generated.

Comment: Aye ok, that makes sense. But how does the client know anything about the enum. It is defined in the service, not the client. How do I get the client to understand it?

Comment: If it is used in service methods (either return types or parameter types) then it should be generated automatically (note that you don't need to write the full attribute name, either, such as `DataContractAttribute` can become `DataContract`).

Comment: It doesnt seem to be, its used as a parameter. All I get is - "The name 'EventReportType' does not exist in the current context" when I try and use it as suggested.

Comment: Perfect :) Can be accessed using `ServerRef.EventReportType.DailyAutoContract` . Cheers. You saved me alot more headache :D I was just missing the `[EnumMember]`.

Comment: Ya, you will need to properly qualify the type name as you describe (namespaces can be awful with services if not thought out properly!) - glad you're up and running again. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any attribute that would expose a class or enum in wsdl directly. The only method I've found so far is to include it as a parameter or return type of a webmethod - something cluttery like:

```
[WebMethod]
public myEnum ExposeEnum()
{
    return myEnum.DefaultValue;
}
```

This will at least make it appear in the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

**As posted earlier at Stackoverflow:**

Using the Common library should be fine. Enumerations are serializable and the DataContract attributes are not needed.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx

"Enumeration types. Enumerations, including flag enumerations, are serializable. Optionally, enumeration types can be marked with the DataContractAttribute attribute, in which case every member that participates in serialization must be marked with the EnumMemberAttribute attribute"

Comment: I've already seen that question/answer, and it was not along the same lines, as it is using a common library (dll) to obtain the enumerated type. Where as I am trying to obtain it from the webservice. i did follow as much of it as I could in similarity, hence having the datacontractattribute flag, but it does not seem to work.